# How to make use of a particular commit of Tensorflow in google colab?

Tags: git, tensorflow, github, google-colaboratory, open-source

I wanted to contribute to open source, & since my interest is towards machine learning, I took up an issue from tf - [issue#59494](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59494).

Here, there's a confusion on why a particular fix [commit f5281e0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f5381e0e10b5a61344109c1b7c174c68110f7629) is cherry picked in v2.10.1, but not in v2.9.3.

The fix is for the error referenced in [CVE-2022-41883](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w58w-79xv-6vcj), namely OOB (out of bounds) error & I'm trying to recreate it.

In colab (*I couldn't install tf in local, so had to use colab*), for both versions, I got the error mentioned in the below image.
[v2.9.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMawt.png)
[v2.10.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikD1e.png)

My thought was to make use of a commit (say, 422d24d3) before the commit f5281e0 is merged, so as to get OOB as the output. I couldn't figure out how to do this, any help is much appreciated :)

Also, is there a better way to address [issue#59494](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59494)?

An update:

I figured out a way to address this & have answered it!

*I'm quite new to open source, please forgive me for any shortcomings & point me in the right direction.*

Answer (score 0):

There's an installation option in [tf github readme](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). Here there's info on how to build from source. Check out the required commit (to recreate the OOB error), using:
!git checkout 422d24d3