# What are the system requirements to build tensorflow from source?

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, google-colaboratory, open-source

As part of learning & trying to recreate an error mentioned in tensorflow issues, I was trying to [build a particular commit from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445336/how-to-make-use-of-a-particular-commit-of-tensorflow-in-google-colab). I'm referring the official documentation to [build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

I encountered an issue with the following command:

`!bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

This command kept running for 5.5 hrs & eventually my free google colab runtime (CPU) was exhausted.

[bazel build timeout from runtime exhaustion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZSEX.png)

What would be the system requirements to build tensorflow from source? How to figure this out?
Will using GPU runtime under the free plan be sufficient to build from source?

[UPDATE]

I faced the timeout issue, as I didn't include --config=opt, as in

`!bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Now I'm getting below error

> Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (498 packag
> INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (498 packages loaded, 29765 targets configured).
> INFO: Found 1 target...
> ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/85204b6082c56565b80becb994288308/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:304:11: Compiling src/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 41 arguments skipped)
> gcc: error: n: No such file or directory
> ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/85204b6082c56565b80becb994288308/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:415:10: Compiling src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 39 arguments skipped)
> gcc: error: n: No such file or directory
> Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
> Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
> INFO: Elapsed time: 129.427s, Critical Path: 0.25s
> INFO: 7 processes: 6 internal, 1 local.
> FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

I think this is related to gcc version, am I on the right track?
My current gcc in collab is 9.4.0. Since I want to build a commit prior to v2.9.3, I referred the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) & decided to try gcc 9.3.1; but how to install this specific version, I haven't found an answer despite searching several links.

Comment: Google Colab will not be a good option to build tensorflow from source. It may take lots of time to complete the process that you also mentioned. You can try using your local machine instead. Please refer to this [link](https://branyang.gitbooks.io/tfdocs/content/install/install_sources.html) as well as TF Official [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to build tensorflow from source and to find the system requisites as per your machine OS type. Let us know in case of any issue.

Comment: @TFer2 thanks for the input. I have a system where I'm not the root user, & I don't have access to installing from source, hence opted for google collab. I think I had tried in my local machine; I'll try once & update. Cheers!